# What is the truth value if any for $f(x)=y$ when $x$ is outside of the domain of $f$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic, provability

What is the truth value if any for $f(x)=y$ when $x$ is outside of the domain of $f$? Could it be false or undefined?

Comment: If you think about it, functions are a sort of mapping between the domain and the codomain. In other words, they originate from within the domain. Outside the domain, there is no such mapping to the codomain, so it won't make sense. That said, there are these things called analytic continuations, which basically preserve a specific trend that the function exhibits, and tries to extend that property beyond the regular domain.

Comment: I would like to draw this to the analogy of a shadow. An opaque object creates a shadow when a bright light shines of it. What shadow would you get if you don't have a light?

Comment: Can you explain why you're interested in this?  What is the possible point of it?

Comment: It is a very strange question, I will admit, but it is actually a point of controversy for someone I thought should know better, someone with supposedly a masters degree in mathematics.

Comment: If $x$ is not in the domain of $f$ then $f(x)$ is undefined and $f(x) = y$ is a false statement.

Comment: @fleablood Can you formally prove that? It seems to me that it would be indeterminate.

Comment: Is it a false statement, or is it not a statement?  If I write $\forall \exists \neg = 42$, is that a false statement?

Comment: Is "Santa Claus is married to the pope" or "Micky Mouse's underwear is made of spaghetti" true or false?  I'd interpret those three sentences to mean "There exists a person who is Santa Claus and he is married to the pope" and "There exist underwear belonging to Micky Mouse and it is made of spaghetti" and "$x$ is in the domain of $f$ and $f(x)=y$".  As such all three are false. But if you interpet them as "all people who are Santa Claus are married to the pope" or "if $x$ is in the domain of $f$ then $f(x)=y$" then they are vacuously true. What do *you* think is the definition of the stament?

Comment: @fleablood, your idea to append "there exists RHS and" to "RHS = LHS" reminds me of Arthur Prior's proposed resolution to the paradox of "This statement is false", which was to say that every statement implicitly begins with "This statement is true and", making the statement "This statement is true and this statement is false" simply false, rather than a paradox.

Comment: I think that $f(x)=y$ with $x$ not in the domain of $f$ would be more similar to ```(a%b4 #-c9 is the Pope``` than to ```Mickey Mouse's underwear is the Pope```, but I don't consider myself even a novice at logic (I've tried to read a few books on formal logic), so I am very curious what experts think on the subject, and if there is a consensus, or disagreement.

Comment: @fleablood Those are dangerously mysterious questions. Is Ahab captain of the Pequod? Is Ahab the cabin boy of the Pequod? https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fictional-entities/.

Comment: Let $f$ be the reciprocal function on its natural/maximal domain. Then $$f(x)=y$$ is an open formula with no definite truth value. On the other hand, both $$∀x{\in}\{0\}\;∃y\:\:f(x)=y$$ and $$∀x \;\big(x=0∧∃y\;f(x)=y\big)$$ are not well-formed formulae (tempting as it may be to call them false statements) since $f(0)$ is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

The natural way to look at it is that the expression is ill-formed and so it doesn't make sense to ask its truth value. This is the case in type-theory-based formalisms.

In something like first-order set theory, though, syntax like $f(x)$ comes from [extension by definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_by_definitions#Definition_of_function_symbols), so your equation is shorthand for a well-formed sentence that does have a truth value. Whether it's true or false depends on technical details that "shouldn't matter" because they don't affect the truth value when the notation is used in the intended way, i.e. when the function argument is an element of the function's domain.

Answer (score 2):

In set theory, where a function is simply a set of ordered pairs satisfying a uniqueness condition, $f(x)= y$ is syntactic sugar defined to mean $(x,y)\in f$. Thus the statement is false if $x \notin \operatorname{domain}(f)$.

In programming, the “truth value” of the 11th element of a 10-element Boolean array is undefined, and trying to access it will raise an index out of bounds exception in languages that perform bounds checking; it would yield garbage in languages that don’t (for example, C).

Comment: Would your argument imply that, in set theory, ```5 + - = 31``` is a false statement?

Comment: No, and huh?  That’s an ill-formed forumula.

Comment: If $f:\mathbb{R}^{3} \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(a,b,c)=a+b-c$, then isn't my previous comment the same as $f(5)=31$, with 5 not in the domain of $f$?

Comment: [*formula, above – typed on phone.] @Joe You're not making sense. What you wrote in your previous comment is "$5 + - = 31$". Your new $f$ expects three arguments not one; $5 \notin \mathbb{R}^3$. I don't think further discussion is fruitful.

Comment: @BrianO Not mere "syntactic sugar," $\forall x: [x \in A \implies f(x) \in B]$ would also solve the problem. We could not use this statement to infer anything about $f(x)$ for $x\notin A.$

Comment: In JavaScript accessing out of bound gives undefined. There is a bound check, but there is no exception but a special value. This is closer to some logical modelling of automated verification of programs.

Comment: @Jean-LucPicard Yes JS is weird in that way :) But thanks for mentioning it — JS is atypical with its forgiving approach, but it's the right choice for a front-end language.

Comment: I still find it odd that you wrote $5 \notin \mathbb{R}^{3}$ as why you thought that I wasn't making sense, when that makes it a perfect example for your post about $x \notin \mathrm{domain}(f)$.

Comment: @DanChristensen But of course, it is syntactic sugar in set theory: the basic language has no notation for applying a function to an argument; that is introduced in a conservative extension by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after much thought, from Terence Tao's, "Analysis I," p. 49, we have the definition:

> **Definition 3.3.1** (Functions). Let $X$, $Y$ be sets, and let $P(x,y)$ be a property pertaining to an object $x \in X$ and an object $y \in Y$, such that for every $x \in X$, there is exactly one $y \in Y$ for which $P(x,y)$ is true (this is sometimes known as the *vertical line test*). Then we define the *function $f : X \to Y$ defined by $P$ on the domain $X$ and range $Y$* to be the object which, given any input $x \in X$, assigns a output $f(x) \in Y$, defined to be the unique object $f(x)$ for which $P(x, f(x))$ is true. Thus, for any $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$, $$y = f(x) \iff P(x,y)\,\text{is true.}$$

Rather than a predicate $P(x,y)$, I prefer to use a *[graph set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Relational_approach)* $G \subseteq X\times Y.$ In the notation of set theory, we can then define the standard "$f(x)$" functional notation as follows:

$\qquad\forall\ G, X, Y:[G\subseteq X\times Y \ \land\ \forall x\in X: \exists! \ y\in Y: (x,y)\in G \\\quad\ \implies \ \exists f: \ \forall x\in X: \forall y\in Y:[y=f(x) \iff (x,y)\in G]]$

From this, we can infer that

$\qquad\forall x\in X : f(x)\in Y$

$\qquad\forall x\in X: (x,f(x))\in G$

Thus $f(x)$ will be *undefined* outside of its domain of definition $X$.

(Though Tao doesn't hint at it, the above definition should perhaps require that the domain $X$ and codomain/range $Y$ be non-empty. Otherwise, it may be impossible to infer anything about $f$.)